# Looking for a PC wireless keyboard for programming

Tags: keyboards

I have spent a lot of time looking for a new keyboard and have not seen one that matches my criteria. For instance as a programmer, to me, the buttons `Home`, `End`, `Delete` are very important but manufacturers commonly decide not to include these or put them in inconvenient places in favour of buttons like `ScrLk`, `Pause`, `Insert` taking the sweet spots (which are buttons I never use by the way). I am looking for a keyboard with the following features:

- US layout
- `CapsLock` (I don't use it either) isn't bigger than `Left Shift`. You have no idea how commonly I hit `CapsLock` instead of `Shift`.
- *Big* `Enter`, preferably on 2 rows, e.g.
  [image]
  My current keyboard has `\` right above `Enter` and I end up pressing the wrong button quite commonly when typing fast.
- `Home`, `End`, `Delete` conveniently placed near other active buttons e.g. above Backspace or at all somewhere near to the rest of the keys. In the middle of a Numpad doesn't quite fit. It works if `Home` and `End` are `Fn+Left/Right Arrow`
- Preferably wireless and slim. I am not a fan of mechanical keyboards and prefer quiet ones as seen for instance on laptops as it lets me type much faster and quieter.
- The final extra would be to have the super key say `super` (not to be confused with an Apple layout) or be a blank key instead of the Windows. Now obviously this is only an extra, although I am not really a fan of having a corporate trademark of a product I do not use stuck on an item I use all the time.

I am by no means asking anyone to search for a keyboard with these criteria for me.; I am posting this just in case you have already seen something like what I described, in which case I would really appreciate the brand and model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spending 30 years next to computers, I think your *exact* wish is not existing, however, just like you also wrote, close enough candidates can be found.

I think a viable one could be **Logitech K800** ([picture](https://www.complies.de/media/catalog/product/cache/3/image/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/t/e/temp_85888.jpg)), I have also used it for some years, even as software specialist.

- US layout: exists
- LShift > Caps: on US layout it is
- Wireless & Slim: it is. (& non-mech)

  **Extra**: illuminated keys :)

  **X** - no 2-row Enter :(

  *Alt* - Del/Home/End location. Honestly I'm not sure what your preference would be with these. I would be happy if you let me know in comments. I get it for FN + L/R, but I know no such manufactured keyboard.

  *Alt* - Super/etc. key location is not fixed. My current Logitech K270 has "context menu" button there, K800 had FN button there.

This is my suggestion with first hand experience. I hope you like it or will find some more suitable one. In the end I'm interested what you find as best fit, I will be happy if you share :)